# How can a .NET code know whether it is running within a web server application?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a library code, which should be aware whether it is executed in the context of a web server or standalone application server.

The obvious that comes to mind is to check the name of the application configuration file and if it is web.config - then this is a web server, otherwise - standalone application server.

Another way is to look for something like "Temporary ASP.NET files" in the path of the shadow folder.

But I dislike both of these, since they seem too hacky and fragile. Is there a robust way to do what I want?

Thanks.

**P.S.**

One may define a dedicated app config setting - IsWebServer, but I dislike it even more.

**EDIT:**

While looking for a solution to another problem, I think I solved this one - the details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091866/how-can-a-net-code-know-whether-it-is-running-within-a-web-server-application/2092246#2092246)

Comment: Why do you need it to be aware of its context?

Comment: We assign a special meaning to the first folder in the private probing path. The thing is, that under the web server our logic should work somewhat differently, because of the differences in private probing path setups between a web server and a standalone app.

Comment: Perhaps you should stub it out so that you would simply store a strategy pattern implementation into your framework, so that the framework itself doesn't need any special code, but the code lives in your web application instead?

Comment: Lasse: Nice idea, nevertheless, he'll probably need to decide to use that on some basis; the basis should be a config setting, IMHO.

Comment: The problem is that it requires explicit config setting. I wish to avoid it.

Comment: mark: I know; as I explained in my post, I think that's a mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trying to solve another problem, I found a good solution for this one.
There is a private method `System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue.IsHostedInAspnet`, which does exactly what I need. Being a private method, I do not want to call it (though I could using reflection), but its implementation is trivial:

```
private bool IsHostedInAspnet()
{
    return (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData(".appDomain") != null);
}
```

(according to Reflector)

Looks like there is a special key in the app domain data - ".appDomain", which is set when running in ASP.NET web server.

I will stick to that.

Comment: I really think this is terrible. It's using an implementation detail that may change. Does it work on Mono? I can't imagine why you wouldn't do the config option. Each to his own.

Comment: @NoonSilk Yeah I've done some Googling and it seems `.appDomain` is not publicly documented. As for Mono, it seems like it would work since the code explicitly sets a value https://github.com/playscript/playscript-mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Hosting/ApplicationHost.cs

Answer (score 7):

You can check for

```
HttpContext.Current
```

If it is not null then it is run from a web app.

See [HttpContext.Current Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx)

Comment: That will only work if it is running in the same thread as the request - subsequently spawned background threads won't have a HttpContext.

Comment: @DrJokepu - precisely. In my case HttpContext.Current is null.

Answer (score 6):

The best option is a config setting.

It's better for testability; it's better because it's an obvious statement of how the code will work, and it's better because it doesn't rely on implementation details; you specifically branch from a value you set. It may be that the decision you are making is non-obvious and your variable/config can be suggestive of the reasoning.

It's the option I'd go for.

Comment: This seems to be a little short sighted to me. For example as the author of a component that can be distributed and sold for use by other developers, I want the licensing to behave differently for web processes than win forms or services or console apps. I don't want the purchasing developer to be able to "lie" about how they are using the component, and I don't want a reference to `System.Web` as my component will work under the .Net Client profile. I want to detect a web environment and internally change the assembly's behavior accordingly. I'm currently researching how best to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can Find out the current process name:

```
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
string assemblyName = p.ProcessName;
```

and then check if this is the [ASP.NET process name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241730(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: And what if it's running in mono?

Comment: I think that the answer will be the same.
The code will be executed under the context of the web server host process.

Answer (score 1):

- BrowserInteropHelper..::.IsBrowserHosted
     Property

> Gets a value that specifies whether
>   the current Windows Presentation
>   Foundation (WPF) application is
>   browser hosted.

*Thats how its done in XBAP*

- [Performing Browser Detection Using
     ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150659/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120402-1.aspx)

*or if you have an appdomain do reflection and get something from it? using*

- [Reflection CallContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think the very best thing to do is to split up the library into 2 dlls, one that's truly generic, and one (the one that requires ASP.NET) that only gets loaded in the website. Checking if it's currently running in ASP.NET feels like a bit of a hack.

Ofcourse it depends on the situation wether or not you can easily do this.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28993766/2856659)...

Basically, you can use [HostingEnvironment.IsHosted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.ishosted(v=vs.110).aspx).